# Python: Import class from args parser

Tags: python, python-import, argparse

I want to know if it is possible to import a class from the input arguments of argsparser.
What I am doing now is something like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-p', dest="process", default="process1")
args = parser.parse_args()

if 'process1' in args.process: from Process1 import analysis
elif 'process2' in args.process: from Process2 import analysis
....
```

I am wondering if there is a way to do something like this:

```
from args.process import analysis
```

Comment: use importlib for lazy loading

Comment: You are trying to do the equivalent of `from 'process1' import analysis'.  `args.process` is a string, not a class.